# Left justification in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I am trying to left justify the contents of the tcolorbox but without success. The minimal example is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\centerline{
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,width=0.6\linewidth]
\centerline{\textbf{First} statement}
\centerline{\textbf{This} is the second statement}
\end{tcolorbox}}
\end{document}
```

Could you please suggest me ideas on how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you think `\centerline` is doing? `;-)`

Comment: Remove `\centerline`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\centerline` centers that specific line.

I've updated your example. Note how I've also updated the environment surrounding environment. Also refer to the tcolorbox-manual on ctan to find out more about alignment within the boxes: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,width=0.6\linewidth]
        \textbf{First} statement \newline
        \textbf{This} is the second statement
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. On a different note, is there a way to automatically fit the size of the tcolorbox depending on the text size?

Comment: Yes! But that would exceed the comment space. If you don't mind, please have a look in the tcolorbox manual on pg. 430 under `\tcbuselibrary{fitting}`. It has large examples too!

Comment: Perfect. Thank you !!

Answer (score -1):

By default the text is left aligned --remove the command to `center`line the text and it will revert to default left align

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\centerline{
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,width=0.6\linewidth]
{\textbf{First} left aligned statement}\\
{\textbf{This} is the second left aligned statement}
\end{tcolorbox}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Careful: `\centerline` is a macro inherited by plain TeX that will center the line _without line-breaking_. It can come in handy in some situations if you know exactly what it does but in general you should better avoid it: you might get nasty surprises.